# jquery 'if interacted with'?

Tags: jquery, hide, show

I'm doing a 'hover to peek' script, and was hoping a guru could give me some guidance. Please read the code first, and then my 'code-speak'

```
$(".peek").mouseenter(function() {
    var $peek = $("#peek");
    if ($peek.data("active")) { return; }
    $peek.show().data("active", true);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $peek.hide().data("active", false);
    }, 1000);
});
```

How can I say: "if $peek has been activated or if $peek has been hidden" do this ()

What my ultimate goal is here:

If hover on .peek, show #peek for 1 second, and then if you've seen #peek, disable the ability to hover on .peek so you can no longer see #peek.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".peek").mouseenter(function() {
    var $peek = $("#peek");
    if (typeof $peek.data("active") !== "undefined") return;

    $peek.show().data("active", true);
    setTimeout(function() {
        $peek.hide().data("active", false);
    }, 1000);
});
```

In your code, `if ($peek.data("active"))` retrieves either `false` or `undefined`, while you only want to run the rest of your code if it is `undefined`.

Comment: I imagine `active` here means *has-been-activated-ever*, and that the code should exit before `show` for any hover after the first one.

Comment: @David That's exactly what my code does. Uhm. After I change `===` to `!==`, of course.

Comment: Well yes, it was the `===` that threw me off there, of course. But I imagine setting it back to `false` is the real mistake, without which the original condition is fine.

Comment: @David I figured the data might be used at some other point, so I left it in. But then again, you're probably right.

Answer (score 1):

On `hide` you're setting `active` to false. If you don't do that, it'd just `return` before showing, on any subsequent hover, right?